# MySQL defaults-file argument not recognized

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

I am trying to log in to mysql with `--defaults-file` option on the command line:

```bash
$ mysql --defaults-file ~/mycnf.cnf
```

But I get the following error:

```
mysql: unknown option '--defaults-file'
```

But this option is listed in the help:

```bash
$ mysql --help
...
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
```

Whats going on here?  Here is the output of mysql --version

```bash
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be:

```sh
mysql --defaults-file=~/mycnf.cnf
```

You were missing the `=`.

Also note that the options used to specify option files must precede any other options. See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html) for specific details.

Comment: I have the same problem, however I **am** already putting the `=` sign, yet the error persist

Comment: Make sure you're typing an ASCII `-` character, not some other character that looks similar. It should be character code 45 decimal, 2D hex.

Comment: I just checked, and my start script had a wrong encoding, corrected id but still no luck ... thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: What happens if you use `mysql --help` and then copy/paste the option to your script?

Comment: Tried that too, still same error... Might be worth to say that I'm trying to use that with mysqld_safe, which should still recognize such option

Comment: Yes, it should. The client application is independent of the server.

Comment: adam_0 comments below: "It seems that mysql and related commands must have the --defaults-file or --defaults-extra-file as the first parameter, or else it won't be recognized." This was the problem I was having - I think it should also appear up here in the accepted answer. This is documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html

Comment: @user1527225 Thanks, I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: don't `mysqldump --no-tablespaces --defaults-file=/var/lib/mysql/.my.cnf`, because if you have a option file it should go first, like: `mysqldump --defaults-file=/var/lib/mysql/.my.cnf --no-tablespaces`. The wrong way may throw: `mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'defaults-file=/root/var/lib/mysql/.my.cnf'`

Comment: Isn't that what I said at the end of my answer?

Answer (score 27):

In my case the issue was **misplacement** of the parameters.

the `--console` parameter should have been last...

My original take:

`mysqld --console --defaults-file="path-to-ini/my.ini"`

While should have run this:

`mysqld --defaults-file="path-to-ini/my.ini" --console`

Comment: Just wanted to let you know this solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: It's actually that `--defaults-file` should be first :-)

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue too. Never thought that would matter!

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem with a similar issue!

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add another answer to this problem to a similar situation I faced.

In my case, the command was similar to this:

```
/path/to/mysqld_safe start --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf --other-options-here
```

and mysql would complain

```
unknown variable '--defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf'
```

In order to solve this, I had to "drop" the `start` command, making the line read like this:

```
/path/to/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf --other-options-here
```

And then mysql would finally start using the specified configuration file.

Comment: It seems that mysql and related commands must have the `--defaults-file` or  `--defaults-extra-file` as the first parameter, or else it won't be recognized.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the same issue using bash/sh script instead of directly on the cli with OSX, I had to use the full path of the mysql.client app.

```
$which mysql
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql
```

MySql was installed by Zend Server as shown by the path below and wrapped the mysql.client version:

```
$mysql --version
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

The error continues to show until I change how my bash script was calling mysql.

From:

```
MYSQL=`which mysql`
...
${MYSQL} --defaults-file=/dev/stdin -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

output

```
$ ./import_dbs.sh
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client: unknown variable 'defaults-file=/dev/stdin'
```

Change to:

```
MYSQL=/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client
...
${MYSQL} --defaults-file=/dev/stdin -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

outputs

```
$ ./import_dbs.sh
Database
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
test
```

Edit:
I could also use the following in my script:

```
MYSQL=`which mysql.client`

$ which mysql.client
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client
```

Evidently there is a slight difference between calling mysql and mysql.client that affects being able to pass --defaults-file or other variables mentioned in the OP as the first parameter, within a script.  I haven't tested via the shell

Comment: This actually the case for me in a bitnami MySQL 5.6 image since `which mysql` is a wrapper at `/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql` over `/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql.bin`. The wrapper has extra handling of `defaults-file`. Side note: `--defaults-extra-file` works even without full path.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> [ERROR] unknown option '--defaults-extra-file'.

When I tried to log in with `--defaults-extra-file` as shown below:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

So, I put `=` just after `--defaults-extra-file` as shown below, then I could log in:

```
                           ↓
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```